# Sorting Q_FLAGS in Designer for a custom widget made in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm creating some custom widgets in PyQt, that are to be used into Qt's Designer.
Some of them have properties as `Q_FLAGS`, for example *some* of the `QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag`. Since I won't use the whole `QtCore.Qt.Alignment` flags (it's unnecessary and creates confusion), I created a QFlags class.

```
class SomeWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    class LabelAlignment:
        AlignLeft = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        AlignHCenter = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        AlignRight = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        AlignTop = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        AlignVCenter = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        AlignBottom = int(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)

    QtCore.Q_FLAGS(LabelAlignment)
```

(Note: I'm using `int()` conversion as I need to do some bitwise operations and, AFAIK, a flag pyqtProperty is always read as `int` within Designer's property sheet; I tried to use plain flags, but the result is the same)

The problem is that the flags are sorted in an unpredictable order within Designer's property editor. I *suppose* that it's due to the use of `LabelAlignment.__dict__` to map the class's flags, thus creating an "unsorted" list of the flags (which, obviously, changes every time Designer loads the plugin interface, since python's dicts are unordered).

Is there any way of ordering those flags (maybe using an OrderedDict)?

Comment: I don't see any evidence that Qt Designer *ever* sorts enums. Looking at the alignment property for a QLabel, for instance, the options are neither sorted by name nor value.

Comment: @ekhumoro You are right, the order seems to be "logical" (specifically set for Designer). The point is that the order of predefined flags is always consistent: for example I used QtCore.Qt.Edge for another property, and the combobox always shows Top/Left/Right/Bottom, while my own property flags order is always different.

Comment: This is something you will have to [take up with the author of pyqt](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt). Internally, a `QHash` is used to store the names/values, which implies arbitrary ordering.